# Integration on Sphere and Stoke's Theorem

Tags: calculus, stokes-theorem

I would like to clarify the not quite correct statement that one hears every now and then
$$
\tag{1}\label{1}
\color{red}{\text{"The sphere has no boundary, and the integrand is a derivative so the integral is zero"}} 
$$

Consider for example
$$
\int_{S^2}d^2x\sqrt{g} \nabla_\mu V^\mu
$$
for some vector field $V^\mu$ on the tangent space of $S^2$. One could now try to use Stoke's theorem as follows
$$
\int_{S^2}d^2x\sqrt{g} \nabla_\mu V^\mu = \int_{S^2}d^2x\;\partial_\mu(\sqrt{g}V^\mu) = \int_{\partial S^2}d\Sigma_\mu\sqrt{g}V^\mu
$$
and conclude that the result is zero because there is no sphere boundary $\partial S^2$. But after taking the standard spherical coordinates where $\sqrt{g} = \sin\theta$, $d^2x = d\theta d\phi$ and setting for example $V^\theta = \frac{\theta}{\sin\theta}$ and $V^\phi = 0$ one sees that $\int_{S^2}d^2x\sqrt{g} \nabla_\mu V^\mu$ gives a non-zero result.

So what is the setting and the conditions so that the statement $\eqref{1}$ is correct? Or maybe better, what is the correct formulation of it? One might think that $\sqrt{g}$ is canceled by the corresponding term in the covariant derivative and one should consider regular derivatives instead of covariant ones. But take for example $\int_{S^2}d^2x\sqrt{g}\; \partial_\theta f(\theta)$ with $f(\theta) = \log\tan(\theta/2)$, $f'(\theta) = 1/\sin\theta$, which gives a non-zero result.

Comment: $\frac{\theta}{\sin\theta}$ explodes at the pole $\theta=\pi$. I don't think it matters that $\sqrt g$ cancels the denominator; the vector $V$ itself is infinite.

Comment: So is the correct statement then "The integral of the covariant divergence of a vector over $S^2$ is zero provided that the vector is regular everywhere"? There is no similar statement for derivatives of scalar functions, right? Because the $\partial_\theta f(\theta)$ example doesn't work even for regular $f(\theta)$ e.g. $f(\theta) = \theta$.

Comment: What does "regular" mean? (I'm not very familiar with differential forms.) The function $\theta$ also has some problems; its gradient points north or south, but what happens at the pole? It's discontinuous.